# gwt dom inputElement type setting

Tags: java, dom, gwt

I read the source of gwt `InputElement` and find out, there is only getter for `InputElement`'s type field.

I believe there is a way to set it, but how? I just cannot believe, I cannot create

```
Document doc = Document.get();
InputElement el = doc.createTextInputElement();
el.setType(); //this method does not exist.
```

How is this done, I would like to see `InputElement` that is `type = number`?

I create input elements like that in code only, it is dynamical list, I cannot use html to give the type.

Source:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/InputElement.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You can add type as an attribute like this:

```
 Document doc = Document.get();
 InputElement input = doc.createTextInputElement();
 input.setAttribute("type", "number");
```

Now, element is of `type = "number"`.

Comment: Some time ago I was trying to change input type from `text` to `password` and it worked well except for IE browser, so be sure to test it extensively...

Comment: @Adam: good point. I will look that before I accept my answer. Cannot do that before two days anyways (site prohibits).

Comment: FWIW, thus is the reason there's no setter for type; there was a time where some browsers (IE?) wouldn't allow setting the type. It might be obsolete now, but nobody took the time to update them API.